# 5 core cable, Graded Bosch PKE611D17E 60cm 4 Zone Ceramic Hob

Tags: electrical

[image: cooker wall plate]

We are working on my son's kitchen. His girlfriend's dad took the Bosch cooker out and took the cable from the Graded Bosch PKE611D17E 60cm 4 Zone Ceramic Hob hob out of the wall plate. I have wired it back in as per the sticker on the 5-core cable (already fitted to the hob). There's nothing -Checked that power was present at the wall plate, and all ok. The breaker is in the on position. Am I missing something?

I've read different posts on this I’ve tried to upload a picture but says it’s too big so just to let you know the wall plate has Red, Y/G, & Black wires.

I have wired the cable

- Brown and Black -> Red,
- Earths as normal
- Grey and Blue -> Black

Comment: Could you add some punctuation, so we know where sentences start & finish. It all just reads like stream-of-consciousness. Imagine we can't see over your shoulder; you have to tell us precisely what happened. If you upload the image to anywhere publicly-available, imgur etc, then someone can inline it here for you.

Comment: If the image is too large, the Paint program on Windows, Gimp on Linux, or presumably some equally standard tool on Mac, can be used to reduce it.

Comment: There are quite a few image compressors for free on the net.   I use them all the time when I attach pics to an email and don't want to annoy my friends by sending a 5Meg pic when a 500K will do just fine.

Comment: Never reduce the **Resolution** of an image until you. have tried reducing the JPEG **Quality**. This will reduce its size monstrously without degrading its resolution.  Open in default application... Save as... JPEG... quality = 3-5 depending on size needed.  I'd much rather have a 4000x5000 pic at Q=3 than a 400x500 pic at Q=12.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are in the UK based on wiring colours (and the back box looks like a UK type to me). I found the installation instructions for the hob [here](https://www.bosch-home.co.uk/product-list/PKE611D17E#/Tabs=section-manuals/Togglebox=accessories/Togglebox=accessoriesOthers/Togglebox=manuals/). On Page 3 it has this to say about 5-core cables:

> Connecting with a pre-installed 5-wire power cable

> The power cable must only be replaced by trained
> customer service personnel.

It looks to me like the model that you have is expecting a multi-phase power supply. I can't see the label clearly (a bigger picture would be helpful), but it looks like the expected connections are:

- green/yellow -> Earth
- grey -> neutral
- blue -> neutral
- brown -> live
- black -> live

but the live connections for brown and black should not go to the same live they are different phases of a multi-phase system. Your back box does not have a 3-phase supply, and it's unlikely that your incoming supply is 3-phase either. Your best option is to take the hob back and get a correct single-phase one.

Just for completeness, the hob wire is using the current wiring colours (green/yellow = earth, blue = neutral, {brown, black, grey} = lives) and your fixed wiring is in the old colour scheme (sleeved green/yellow = earth, black = neutral, {red, blue, yellow} = lives).

Also it looks like there may be alternative wiring schemes on the label. if you post pictures showing every part of the label, there may be a way to wire it.